# Insert rows based on difference between value from col A row N and col B row N+1

Tags: r

I have data with an example as follows (I use `R`):

```
A   B   C
1   2   Background
3   19  Background
26  41  person
43  69  person
83  97  Background
107 129 Background
132 179 Background
189 235 Background
243 258 Background
261 279 person
```

I would like to add rows where the difference between col A row N+1 and col B row N > 1 and row C gets a label (e.g. 'other'). So the data would look like this:

```
A   B   C
1   2   Background
3   19  Background
20  25  other
26  41  person
43  69  person
70  82  other
83  97  Background
98  106 other
107 129 Background
130 131 other
132 179 Background
180 188 other
189 235 Background
236 242 other
243 258 Background
259 260 other
261 279 person
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way using base R, assuming the 4th row `A` value is 42 (and not 43).

```
#Find out row indices where difference of A value for N + 1 row and 
#B value in N row is not equal to 1.
inds <- which(tail(df$A, -1) - head(df$B, -1) != 1)
#Create a dataframe which we want to insert in the current dataframe
#using values from A and B column and inds indices
include_df <- data.frame(A = df$B[inds] + 1,B = df$A[inds + 1] - 1, C = 'other', 
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#Repeat rows at inds to make space to insert new rows
df <- df[sort(c(seq_len(nrow(df)), inds)), ]
#Insert the new rows in their respective position
df[inds + seq_along(inds), ] <- include_df
#Remove row names
row.names(df) <- NULL

df
#     A   B          C
#1    1   2 Background
#2    3  19 Background
#3   20  25      other
#4   26  41     person
#5   42  69     person
#6   70  82      other
#7   83  97 Background
#8   98 106      other
#9  107 129 Background
#10 130 131      other
#11 132 179 Background
#12 180 188      other
#13 189 235 Background
#14 236 242      other
#15 243 258 Background
#16 259 260      other
#17 261 279     person
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(1, 3, 26, 42, 83, 107, 132, 189, 243, 261
), B = c(2L, 19L, 41L, 69L, 97L, 129L, 179L, 235L, 258L, 279L
), C = c("Background", "Background", "person", "person", "Background", 
"Background", "Background", "Background", "Background", "person"
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Ideally the solution would have included a way to skip, but I realize that might be problematic - in the end it works fine where I have a difference of only 1 I can just filter out that row post-hoc.

Comment: what do I do if there's a 4th column in the mix? I run into an error...let's say rows 1-5 are id == 1 and rows 6-10 are id == 2?

Comment: What value of `id` would you like to give in that case? Or you want to do the same operation for each `id` separately ?

Comment: I'd like to keep id equal to its original value (so if id == 1 for rows 1-5, then include_df incorporates that information). I'm working on applying the same operation over each id, which isn't that hard, but thought there might be an easier solution within the answer you provided in base R.

Comment: I think it should work as it is if you include `ID = df$ID[inds]` in the `include_df` dataframe call.  `include_df <- data.frame(A = df$B[inds] + 1,B = df$A[inds + 1] - 1, C = 'other', ID = df$ID[inds],stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

An option using `data.table` using same data edit as Ronak:

```
ix <- DT[shift(A, -1L) - B > 1L, which=TRUE]
rbindlist(list(DT,
    data.table(A=DT$B[ix]+1L, B=DT$A[ix+1L]-1L, C="other")))[order(A)]
```

output:

```
      A   B          C
 1:   1   2 Background
 2:   3  19 Background
 3:  20  25      other
 4:  26  41     person
 5:  42  69     person
 6:  70  82      other
 7:  83  97 Background
 8:  98 106      other
 9: 107 129 Background
10: 130 131      other
11: 132 179 Background
12: 180 188      other
13: 189 235 Background
14: 236 242      other
15: 243 258 Background
16: 259 260      other
17: 261 279     person
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("A   B   C
1   2   Background
3   19  Background
26  41  person
42  69  person
83  97  Background
107 129 Background
132 179 Background
189 235 Background
243 258 Background
261 279 person")
```